# How can I use context vars in other file in python 3.7 or above?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, importerror, python-contextvars

I have a context var in in file a.py and I want to use it in b.py.

**a.py:**

```
import contextvars

cntx = contextvars.ContextVar("abcd")
```

**b.py:**

```
from .a import cntx

print(cntx.get())
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .a import cntx
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Isn't this how context variables supposed to work?
I'm using python 3.9

Comment: from ./a import cntx is throwing syntax error at / and

from a import cntx is throwing 
LookupError: <ContextVar name='abcd' at 0x7f7d6209c5e0> it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: @Jay `from ./a import cntx` is definitely not correct

Comment: @Jay because that is not valid python syntax. It doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ImportError` that you are getting is because of the invalid file name. `.a` is a valid file name and would work if you had a file with filename being `.a.py`

The reason you are getting the `LookupError: <ContextVar name='abcd' at 0x7f7d6209c5e0>` is because you are trying to `get()` the context which hasn't been set yet.

The [**get()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) method raises a LookupError if no context was set before.

Try with following -

**a.py:**

```
import contextvars

cntx = contextvars.ContextVar("abcd")
cntx.set("example")
```

**b.py:**

```
from a import cntx
print(cntx.get())
```

When you run **`b.py`** -

**Output:**

```
example
```